# Can I cancel only one thread when iterating over parallel.foreach?

Tags: .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

When I use `parallel.foreach`, is there a way to cancel one specific thread?

I know that I can cancel all the threads with `cancelToken.token` using `parallelOptions()`, but how can I cancel **one specific thread**?

I know that if I was creating a list of threads instead of `parallel.foreach`, there is no problem choosing a thread to cancel, but I want my program to run in parallel order and not just async (because I want to use all my CPUs and not just slicing the CPU resources).

Comment: Could you explain what are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you want to stop a thread, or an iteration of the loop? If it's really a thread, why? `Parallel.ForEach` mostly manages the threads for you, you shouldn't need to do anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Okay, so my first thought was bad, but this works:

```
List<string> Items = new List<string>()
{
    "First",
    "Second",
    "Third",
    "Fourth"
};

Parallel.ForEach(Items, (s, t) =>
{
    if (s == "Second")
        return;
    Console.WriteLine(s);
});
```

I guess that'll teach me to fire off answers without waiting for Visual Studio, lesson learned :P

Comment: No, you can not use a continue in a Parallel.ForEeach. The equivalent would be just calling `return;` or `return local;` from the body function depending on if you used the [`Action` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991604(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`Func` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783634(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I got it as soon as I fired up VS and remembered that Parallel.ForEach has a delegate in its signature. Sorry for the misdirection.

Answer (score 2):

As [William Xifaras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688357/william-xifaras) have already mentioned, if you use `Parallel.Foreach` or `Parallel.For` then `ThreadPool` will be used to execute your code.

Why don't you use `Task<T>` to write some similar functionality but with cancellation in mind like this.

```
        Action<CancellationToken> work = (token) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Work started on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Work cancelled on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    return;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Work complete on Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        };

        var tasks = new List<Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource>>();

        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 4))
        {
            var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var task = Task.Run(() => work(cancellation.Token), cancellation.Token);
            tasks.Add(new Tuple<Task, CancellationTokenSource>(task, cancellation));
        }

        tasks.First().Item2.Cancel();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.Select(m => m.Item1).ToArray());
```

This will produce similar output:

```
Work started on Thread: 3
Work started on Thread: 6
Work started on Thread: 4
Work started on Thread: 5
Work cancelled on Thread: 3
Work complete on Thread: 6
Work complete on Thread: 5
Work complete on Thread: 4
```

Is this what you tried to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the Parallel class uses the [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to queue and execute the work.

To answer your question, I do not think there is a way you can cancel a specific "thread" per se, however you can break from a Parallel.For without using the cancellation token.

See the following on MSDN: How to: [Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx).